# What does -200px mean?

Tags: css

I don't know `-200px` mean what in this sense, can you help me?

```
background: url("header.png") repeat-x -200px;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the background should be horizontally positioned at 200px to the left and vertically at the center.

quoting [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position#Values)

> Accepts one or two values, up to four values in supporting browsers.
>   Negative `<percentage>` and `<length>` values are allowed.
>
> **If only one value is specified, the second value is assumed to be center.**
>    The first value represents the horizontal position and the second represents the vertical position (if at least one value is not a
>   keyword).

Answer (score 0):

It is simply the background position from the left

Comment: yeah, it's the position of the background picture